# How does picard's MarkDuplicate handle unmapped reads?

Tags: picard, markduplicate

Our BAM files are created according to a "lossless" alignment procedure [[1](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/article.php?id=6483)] from the Broad Institute `GATK` documenation and involves re-adding the unaligned/unmapped reads into an aligned BAM,  using Picard's `MergeBamAlignment`.

The BAM files are produced in the end contain both the mapped and the unmapped reads. These files are then sorted with [SortSam](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360036510732-SortSam-Picard-) [[2](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360036510732-SortSam-Picard-)]- so that the sort order in the header becomes:

`@HD VN:1.6 SO:coordinate`

How does `MarkDuplicates` handle the unmapped reads of a BAM file containing both unmapped and mapped?

**Note** `MarkDuplicates` seems to normally take the BAM's ordering into account, namely, it accepts arguments such as `--ASSUME_SORT_ORDER X`.  However it's not specified whether reads without a position are ignored, or have to be compared with all other possible reads.

---

*Disclaimer*: I initially posted this question on the GATK forum [[3](https://gatkforums.broadinstitute.org/gatk/discussion/24557/)], but I'm reaching out to hopefully a broader audience.

Citations:

- 1 [How to Map and clean up short read sequence data efficiently](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/article.php?id=6483)
- 2 [SortSam (Picard)](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360036510732-SortSam-Picard-)
- 3 [Original posting on the GATK forum](https://gatkforums.broadinstitute.org/gatk/discussion/24557/)

Comment: Why not just look and see? I'm not sure what it would biologically mean to mark an unmapped read as a PCR duplicate though, it's unclear upon what basis picard would know to do that.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Picard documentation](https://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/picard-metric-definitions.html#DuplicationMetrics):

> DUPLICATION METRICS:
> Metrics that are calculated during the process of marking duplicates within a stream of SAMRecords.

> UNMAPPED_READS    The total number of unmapped reads examined. (Primary, non-supplemental)

It won't alter the flags on these reads, but it will count them in the summary report it generates.
You should be able to test this yourself with a small set of mapped + unmapped reads